# How to configure maven Javadoc plug-in for a multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, multi-module, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am currently working on a multi-module project and using Javadoc to make the code more understandable for co-developers and anyone who would read the code. However, when compiling the project, it generates two jar files for each module, one with the compiled classes and one with the Javadoc. When coding a module which depends on another (dao-mysql, which depends on core, for example), the Javadoc of the dependency is not present. I tried changing the goal and phase, along with some configurations, but it made the Javadoc stop running. What configuration or plugin am I missing? Or can this not be fixed?

This is my project's pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.blackcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>sysloc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-snapshot</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>dto</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>idao</module>
        <module>dao-mysql</module>
        <module>dao-postgresql</module>
        <module>view</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <release>11</release>
                            <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```